# Can't boot into ubuntu even after clean install 18.04 (nvidia graphics card) - stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Using my 18.04 for several months working fine, until suddenly I get the following error upon boot:

```
/dev/sbd6: clean, 138388/2842624 files, 1188280/11370496 blocks
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type " journalctl -xb"  
to view system logs, " systemctl reboot"  to reboot, " systemctl default"
or " exit"  to boot into default mode. Press Enter for maintenance.
```

I use a Nvidia Geforce 940MX Graphics card, for which I installed drivers on Ubuntu. Upon reading other threads, I think this might be the issue. Though the system has worked fine for several months until today.This morning when booting once, I got once the following error preceding along with the previously cited error message

```
Coudn' t get size: 0x800000000000000e
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus:MMIO read of 000000000 FAULT at 612004 [IBUS]
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus:MMIO read of 000000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [IBUS]
```

Because I assumed this error comes from my NVIDIA graphics drivers, I tried to:

- blacklist nouveau drivers in /etc/modprobe.d/ conf file
- format sbd6 and reinstall ubuntu 18.04

I have also tried to repair the disk from a live USB, assuming it was an orphaned inode problem, using the below with various

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb6 
sudo e2fsck -c /dev/sdb6
```

All of it to no avail. What can I do? Why does a clean install of ubuntu not solve the problem?

I was using kernel 4.19, but same problem after clean install of 4.15